GetTable push dataset rest API not returning table in PowerBI
I have created a push semantic dataset, and i pushed record into it using Rest API's in c#. But when i try to get table from it, it keep returns me null column and rows, the response is this :
{
"odatacontext": null,
"value": [
{
"name": "RealTimeData",
"columns": null,
"rows": null,
"measures": null,
"isHidden": null,
"description": null,
"source": []
}
]
}
is any one has any idea, how to get table from push semantic dataset, i am using service principal authenticated web api, which has all the read and write rights.
I already have given read and write rights to service principal, pushed records into dataset, using the context of same service principal.
